# How to add List<> values to gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I created a asp.net website. and added a class file to it. i wrote this code in classfile.(person.cs)

```
public class Person
{
public string name{get; set;}
public int age { get; set; }
public float sal { get; set; }

public Person(string n, int a, float s)
{
    name = n;
    age = a;
    sal = s;
}


public List<Person> getDetails()
{
    Person p1 = new Person("John",21,10000);
    Person p2 = new Person("Smith",22,20000);
    Person p3 = new Person("Cena",23,30000);
    List<Person> li = new List<Person>();
    li.Add(p1);
    li.Add(p2);
    li.Add(p3);
    return li;
}

}
```

and i want this list to display in my gridview.

so, i have added a default page in website. then what should i write in default.aspx.cs file?so that my list values are shown on gridview?

Thanks.

Comment: grdview.DataSource = getDetails(); grdview.DataBind();

Comment: my getDetails() method is in class file. i cant access it from default.aspx.cs ??

Comment: yes... default is also a class.

Comment: thanks for your help. i got the right solution from ankit. thanks again :)

Comment: ASP.NET perhaps hasn't compiled your .cs files. Add your class in the App_Code or set the build Action to "Compile" for your class.

Comment: its compiled. but how can i access a method which is in external class file? to do so i have to change the method to static. and access the method as gridview1.datasource=person.getDetails();  my problem is solved. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the method static:

```
public static List<Person> getDetails()
{
    Person p1 = new Person("John",21,10000);
    Person p2 = new Person("Smith",22,20000);
    Person p3 = new Person("Cena",23,30000);
    List<Person> li = new List<Person>();
    li.Add(p1);
    li.Add(p2);
    li.Add(p3);
    return li;
}
```

And use it from default.aspx.cs like this:

```
    gridView.DataSource = Person.getDetails();
    gridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access you getDetails(); method from class file as follows:

```
Person per=new Person();

grdview.DataSource=per.getDetails();
grdview.DataBind();
```

Comment: oh.. thanks. its working. but what should i give inside Person() ?? i have given some values(like person ("name",age,sal) but its showing only 3 rows which i have added to list in Person.cs.

Comment: thanks for your help. instead of declaring a person again here, i changed my getDetails method to static. its working fine.. thanks again..

Comment: without declaring static you can also access your getDetails() method as per i have shown to you.